# C# string.Split() not working

Tags: c#, string, loops, foreach, split

I wrote this code to look through each parameter in a string.
The string looks like this: "render::rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200, Red, 2)"
This is my code:

```
if (line.StartsWith("render::rectangle(")) {
    foreach(string parameterItem in line.Split('(', ')')) {
        string parameterIt = parameterItem;
        int posX = 0;
        int posY = 0;
        int width;
        int height;
        string colour = "White";
        int borderThickness = 0;
        int paramNum = 0;
        foreach(string parameter in parameterItem.Split(',')) {
            paramNum++;
            string param = parameter;
        }
    }
 }
```

This returns "render::rectangle", why is the Split() not working for this string? Please help.

Comment: What should be your desired output?

Comment: Each parameter between the commas in the paranthesis. For example: when it loops through the first parameter value should be = "0", then "0", "200", "200", "Red" and then "2".

Comment: Hint: you've got two loops there. Why? Your first "loop" should actually just extract everything between `(` and `)` as `parameterItem`. Why would you have a loop there? And why are you declaring extra pointless variables `param` and `parameterIt`?

Comment: The problem is that It still showing it even when I slimmed down the string to split the contents in between a pair of paranthesis on a line in a string. Also the paramerterIt was for debugging purposes to figure out if it was getting anything else on the first loop other than "render::rectangle", my mistake should've taken the code out. I tried this same code out with different strings starting values and it worked for all of them except this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
foreach (string parameterItem in line.Substring(18, line.Length - 18).Split(','))
```

On the first loop, the resulting string would be:

```
0, 0, 200, 200, Red, 2
```

That's the time you can apply your split specifically:

```
Split(',')
```

Now if your string is changing or dynamic, you can get the length of your startswith, then put it in your substring, example:

```
int startLength = @"render::rectangle(".Length;
foreach (string parameterItem in line.Substring(startLength, line.Length - startLength).Split(','))
```